# Multiple connections on the same port socket C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

I need to accept multiple connections to the same port.
I'm using socket in C++, i want to do something like the SSH do.
I can do an ssh user@machine "ls -lathrR /" and run another command to the same machine, even if the first one still running.

How can i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: If it is not for understanding socket programming, I'd suggest not to use plain sockets. Instead use a network framework. [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE-overview.html) or [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/). Initially it looks like a good idea to do vanilla sockets, but it gets messy over time.

Comment: I tried to listen the port again in another thread, but it didn't worked, it says the port is in use so i asked ;)

Comment: There's nothing special you need to do. You are still listening, so don't try to listen again.

Comment: I tried to listen again the same port while i was receiving data and i received the problem that i cannot bind the port

Comment: Why would you try to listen again? You are *already* listening. Of course you can't bind that socket to the port -- you already have a socket bound to the port. (Unless you closed it, in which case, *don't do that*.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you want is a multithreaded socket server.

For this, you need a main thread that opens up a socket to listen to (and waits for incoming client connections). This has to go into a while loop of some sort.

Then, when a client connects to it, the `accept()` function will unblock and at that point you need to serve the client request by passing on the request to a thread that will deal with it.

The server side will loop back and wait for another connection whilst the previous thread carries on its task.

You can either create threads as you need, or use a thread pool which might be more efficient (saving on time initialising new threads).

Have a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2477/Multi-threaded-Client-Server-Socket-Class) for some more details. 
Look for multithreaded server socket on the web, specifically `bind()`, `listen()` and `accept()` from the server side.

Comment: I'll try it, because if i want to connect it says address already in use.

Comment: this can happens if you're trying to bind to port already in use by another application. what port are trying to listen on?

Comment: i need 2 applications to send data to the same port, like ssh does when you send more than 1 command at the same time.

Comment: @November, if by thread you mean the function that will process connection data, then `accept()` goes in the main thread. After the `accept()` call, you can start new thread to deal with that particular connection. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets#Client-server_example_using_TCP for some ex.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on `::listen()` and `::accept()`.

The former will set up your socket for listening.  You then need a loop (probably in its own thread) which uses `::accept()` which will return each time a new connection arrives.

That loop should then spawn a new thread to which you should pass the file descriptor received from `::accept()` and then handles all I/O on that socket from thereon.

Answer (score 0):

Old question is old, but I feel no one who answered understood the OP's question.

You're misunderstanding how ssh works. When you send multiple commands/multiple connections to a server over ssh, there is actually only ONE program on the server you're connecting to that is receiving all those commands.

Sshd (the ssh daemon) runs on the server, and is a multithreaded socket server (see fduff's answer). This is the only program that listens on port 22, and handles all incoming ssh connections by itself.